# Каталонія чи Каталунія?

Tags: фонетика

Катало́нія (кат. Catalunya, окситан. Catalonha, ісп. Cataluña) - автономний регіон Іспанії.

Завжди думала, що правильно говорити саме "Каталонія", але останнім часом чую, що говорять і "Каталунія". То який же варіант є правильним? В мережі нічого не знайшла з цього приводу.

Comment: Іспанське Cataluña та каталонське Catalunya вимовляється ближче до "Каталунья" ніж до "Каталонія". Але фонетична близкість не означає літературну правильність з точки зору української мови.

Answer (score 1):

У [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%8F) знаходжу варіант:

> **Катало́нія**

В [Орфографічному словнику slovnyk.ua](https://www.slovnyk.ua/index.php?swrd=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9) утворено прикметник від цього слова, але творення спостерігаємо однакове:

> **КАТАЛОНСЬКИЙ**, -а, -е. Стос. ***Каталонії*** і каталонців. ** Каталонська мова – мова каталонців.

Навіть в [українсько-польському словнику Glosbe](https://uk.glosbe.com/uk/pl/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%8F) є стаття, присвячена цьому слову:

> **Каталонія**

Отже, літературним є варіант **Каталонія**.

Comment: [«Словник української мови» в 20 томах](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=204890&page=1292) і [«Словники України on-line» від УМІФ](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/) підтримують Ваш висновок.

Comment: Дякую за доповнення!

Answer (score 0):

## Першовимова

За каталоньскої через звучневої міжнародної абетки є [*[kətəˈluɲə]*](//google.com.ua/search?q=k%C9%99t%C9%99%CB%88lu%C9%B2%C9%99&lr=-lang_ru&safe=off). Украӥньська звуку *шва*, тобто *[ə]*, не має, але вже передаємо як *а*. Тому за першовимовою найблизькіше є [***Каталуня***](//google.com.ua/search?q="%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BD%D1%8F"&lr=-lang_ru&safe=off), так і записали булґарцї, а посеред украӥньської таке майже не зустрічається.

Однак, таке слово незвично відмінювати, можливе непорозуміння, тобто *ня* може вказувати на жінку, а також чутливо відріжняється від узвичаєного наростка *ія*  для краӥн. Тому матимемо згадане [***Каталунія***](//google.com.ua/search?q="%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%8F"&lr=-lang_ru&safe=off), котре вже частіше стрічається, хоча переважно як повна назва чи чогось иншого. Але і тут є недоліки з наслїдуванням першовимови: украӥньська зберігає корінь *каталунь* для усього подальшого. Тобто наприклад *каталуньцї*, але вони себе вже звуть [*catalans*](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%86%D1%96) — *каталанс*.

## Літературна

Тому літературна, узвичаєна чи унормована  насправді є непоганим способом назвати так краӥну, тобто [***Каталонія***](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%8F), або точніше кореня *каталонь* (під впливом московської/их звук/знак *ь* [правописно](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil1.htm#par16p2b) викидається — [*каталонський*](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=204890&page=1292)). Бо ненаголошенне *о* [може](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%96%D1%8F_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8#[%D0%BE]) наближатися до *у* чи рідше *а*, правда, маємо недоліка: тут *о* наголошена.